# Add attributes to Builder tag dynamically

Tags: ruby, builder

That may be a shitty title. If anyone has a better idea for how to describe this question, happy to hear it.

If I'm building an XML document with ElementTree in Python, I can do something along the lines of

```
tag = ET.SubElement(root, 'tag')
tag.set('foo', 'true')
if bar
  tag.set('baz', 'false')
```

But with Builder in Ruby, The only way I can see how to set tag attributes is to do the following:

```
xml.tag :foo => 'true', :baz => 'false'
```

Is there a way for me to assign `baz` later after that point? Or do I have to rewrite the entire thing like so:

```
if bar
  xml.tag :foo => 'true', :baz => 'false'
else
  xml.tag :foo => 'true', :baz => 'true'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is more clear when you don't update in-place. Why not this?

```
xml.tag :foo => 'true', :baz => (bar ? 'true' : 'false')
```